# Difference between prefix/postfix increment in Objective-C method call?

Tags: objective-c, operators

I understand the difference between prefix and postfix notation in plain C.

I was, however, wondering if the same rules applied to Objective-C method calls like

```
[myObject foo:++i];
```

and

```
[myObject foo:i++];
```

Or is the "inner C expression" always evaluated first, the two method calls thus yielding the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same rules apply.  Obj-c is a strict superset of c so all things that work in c will work the exact same in Objective-c.

```
++i
```

Will increment `i` before the method is called so those 2 methods will not yield the same result (assuming, or course, that the result depends on the value of `i`).  One is called after `i` is incremented, the other is called before.

---

Comment: I just tried it and it is indeed the way you say. I don't, however, think the "superset" argument is a very good one in this particular case as it could possibly have been that Objective-C evaluated C expressions separately and just inserted the final result into the method call statement.

Answer (score 2):

Why not actually try it and find out?

The result is as would be expected the prefix version operates before the method call. The postfix operates after the method call.

Answer (score 1):

it's the same as C. ObjC is a superset of C.